# Python | Pandas how to split list inside column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, multiple-columns

If have loaded a numpy file as a pandas dataframe

```
train_data = np.load('c:/data_raw/data.npy')
data = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
data.head()
```

The head looks like this
[image]

> **My question**: How can I split the second column (=1) which contains a list
> of variables into multiple columns?

Comment: @yatu: Thanks for the comment. But I dont want to split the columnt into multple rows but rather into multiple columns.

Comment: @DanielMasejo: The linked question asks for the method to transform one list into multiple rows. But I want multiple columns instead.